# pytest can't handle Unicode in doctest in README under Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, pytest, doctest

I have a `README.rst` file containing several doctests for my Python library.  They all work, except for the last doctest, which `print`s Unicode output, encoded in UTF-8:

```
Here is a failing example::

    >>> print(u'\xE5\xE9\xEE\xF8\xFC')
    åéîøü
```

(The use of `print` rather than just a string is very important to my actual use-case, as the real string contains embedded newlines and I need to show off how things on different lines are aligned.)

Running `pytest README.rst` works successfully with Python 3.6.5 and pytest 3.6.1, but under Python 2.7.10, it fails with a very long traceback that ends with:

```
input = 'åéîøü
', errors = 'strict'

    def decode(input, errors='strict'):
>       return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
E       UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py:16: UnicodeEncodeError
```

Setting `setenv = LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` in `tox.ini` and running under tox changes nothing; neither does adding `doctest_encoding = utf-8` to the `[pytest]` section of `tox.ini`.  I see no doctest options relevant to my plight.  How do I get the test to run successfully under Python 2.7?

**Update:** The bug responsible for this problem has been fixed in pytest 3.6.2.

Comment: Works for me with an UTF-8 test.rst even if my locale is ru_RU.KOI8-R. No additional configuration. Python 2.7.13, pytest 3.6.1. Please show a failing example.

Comment: @phd: Example added.  I think the key thing here may be the use of `print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `print` is the culprit. The most interesting part of the exception is this:

```
def getvalue(self):
    result = _SpoofOut.getvalue(self)
    if encoding:
        result = result.decode(encoding)
```

local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/doctest.py:509:

`pytest` tries to decode unicode, so Python tries to encode it first — and fails. I think this is a bug in pytest: it should test if `result` is bytes or unicode:

```
    if encoding and isinstance(result, bytes):
        result = result.decode(encoding)
```

Please report it to pytest issue tracker. You can test the fix and if it
works you can send a pull request.

Comment: [Bug reported](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3583) and [PR opened](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/3584); thanks!